# Passing parameters from ADF Data flow to Dataset used as source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to dynamically pass parameter from pipeline to the dataset that is being used as source from Data Flow.

**Details**

Creating a Data flow that would be called from the Azure data factory pipeline.
Dataflow takes data from the REST andpoint, so I have a Data Set used as source (The data set will call a REST linked service)

So, my calling sequence looks this

```
Pipeline -> DataFlow -> REST DataSet -> RestLinkedService
```

The data set takes parameter such as a base URL and the endpoint url.  The requirement is that base URL is defined in the ADF Global parameters and not anywhere else.  So, it should get dynamically be passed through the calling sequence.
My data set is:
[image]

and it's parameters section is like this:
[image]

Here is what I do not understand :
I create a parameter in the data source, expecting it be populated with what is comming from the pipeline when it runs the Data Flow Activity.  And I do know how to pass a parameter from pipeline to the data flow being called.
However, when I choose that data set in the Dataflow source definition, I have no way to provide the parameters.  What am missing ?  This is what I see in the Dataflow definition
[image]

I found that when we run dataflow debug, there is a "Debug Settings" where I can specify the parameter.  And If I use it, it will work and connect.  However !! The problem I have is, that in the debug setting I **HARDCODE** the parameter value.  There is no option to enter dynamic content.  Or am I not looking in the right place ?  And this is **NOT WHAT IS INTENDED**.
[image]

How do I pass the dynamically passed parameter?
Also, is that section "Debug setting" the right place?  Eventually the pipeline will be triggered on the schedule or via the Rest call by a 3rd party in production environment..... So, I won't be the one "debugging" the dataflow.  What concept am I Missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a debug session in data flow is to act as a testing platform for your transformations. It does not write any data to sink. Just it is used to preview the data. In order to pass the dynamic value, debug session is not the correct place. Use the `parameters` in `Execute Data Flow` activity in the pipeline to send the parameter value from the pipeline to the data flow activity. Using this, you can define the parameter value in the pipeline before passing it to the data flow activity. Below is the approach.

- In the data flow activity of the pipeline -> under source parameter all the dataset parameters that are created in the dataflow will be listed.
- To define the dataset parameter `pBaseURL` of the dataflow, click add dynamic content and type the dynamic value. [image]
- Once you defined the value, you can run the pipeline by debug option of pipeline or schedule it by trigger.